# Better way to identify CorruptedStateExceptions

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.5, corrupted-state-exception

Let's give it another try with less overhead:

**How to determine if an Exception is a CorruptedStateException?**

From what I know there's no common superclass that all CorruptedStateExceptions inherit (exclusively) from and I found no other property/flag/attribute I could use to identify them.

For now the best I could come up is working in 2 steps: In below case `ThirdPartyCall` has the Attributes `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` and `[SecurityCritical]` set to catch CorruptedStateExceptions while `ThirdPartyCallInternal` doesn't. If `ThirdPartyCallInternal` catches an Exception it's no CSE, if only `ThirdPartyCall` catches it, it's one.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
public static void ThirdPartyCall()
{
    bool thrownExceptionIsCorruptedState = true;
    try
    {
        ThirdPartyCallInternal(ref thrownExceptionIsCorruptedState);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (thrownExceptionIsCorruptedState)
        {
            //This is pretty much the only thing we'd like to do...
            log.Fatal("CorruptedStateException was thrown",ex);
        }
        throw;
    }
}

private static void ThirdPartyCallInternal(ref bool thrownExceptionIsCorruptedState)
{
    try
    {
        ThirdPartyLibrary.DoWork();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Exception was caught without HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions => it's not a corruptedStateException
        thrownExceptionIsCorruptedState = false;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there any other (cleaner, easier,...) way to determine if an Exception is a CorruptedStateException that will bring the Application down?

Comment: The odds that an exception has *not* corrupted the state of your program when it is caught by that catch-em-all block are very close to zero.  The *bool* will always be true.  Rethrowing it makes no sense, use Environment.FailFast()

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear: In my opinion the bool will most likely rarely be true. The action can be IDbConnection.Open or any other code. Instead of calling IDbConnection.Open directly I'd like to pass it to InvokeAndLogCorruptedState(()=>IDbConnection.Open) so at least I get all logs. This call to open can pretty much raise all sort of Exceptions (and hopefully only rarely a corrupted state).
If it's an argumentException, DbException,... I (as library developer) can't decide on how to deal with it - the application calling me has to deal with that.

Comment: Nevertheless: Environment.FailFast can be a good option (I don't know anything about it yet) instead of rethrowing the CorruptedState Exception - it's just that I need to know which one is corrupted state and which one ain't in that case too.

Comment: That this is a library is not a small detail.  A library has no business enforcing its own exception handling policy onto the client app.  You should not write this code at all.  If the real intent of this code is to pass the blame around then log before and after you make the call.

Comment: It's not about passing blame - it's about knowing it happened. From what I see no exception handling itself is done - it's just logged. Isn't this behavior transparent to application developers themself? From what I know above code shouldn't make a difference to them on how the code they're calling behaves.
Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Exceptions make a loud bang when they are raised.  If the client app wants to know about them, like it should, then the programmer writes an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  Exactly where it is logged and where the info is sent is not up to a library, primary support responsibility is with the app owner.   Whether or not he'll deal with the nasty ones is his decision, not yours.  Don't make his life miserable.

Comment: I updated the question - I hope the intented use is clearer. Do you see any downsides on this approach?

Comment: Of course, you are making his life miserable.  How is he supposed to choose which method to use?  How is he supposed to get his hands on the log file?

Comment: As we're using log4net he can configure it anywhere he wants it to be - the library is plugging in to the existing configuration. 
You're suggesting that instead of providing an extension method he can use to log, it's better that application developers should take care of it himself, implement the HandleProcessCorruptExceptions everywhere he needs it to be and change his application logic? (and then faces the original question to decide how to deal with it)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's a misunderstanding: "corrupted state" is more a flag on any other type of exception than an exception on its own. Therefore your statement

```
log.Fatal("CorruptedStateException was thrown",ex);
```

is incorrect. There is no exception of type CorruptedStateException thrown. The real exception type could e.g. be AccessViolationException and you should look into the reason of that.

Therefore I think it's not important that an Exception is a corrupted state exception or not. It's important that your application actually catches the exception, you get notified about it and you can fix it.

Doing so simplifies your code to

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
public static void ThirdPartyCall()
{
    try
    {
        ThirdPartyLibrary.DoWork();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        //This is pretty much the only thing we'd like to do...
        log.Fatal("Exception was thrown",ex);
        Environment.FailFast("Fatal exception in 3rd party library");
    }
}
```

Besides that, maybe it's better to let the operating system handle this crash rather than trying to write something into a log file. Note that log4net may also have been destroyed already and writing to the log file is not possible any more.

Instead, register for [Windows Error Reporting](https://sysdev.microsoft.com/), get the crash dumps from Microsoft and analyze those.

Comment: You're right, I've probably misused the term CorruptedStateException, I took it from the HandleProces...Attribute but I guess Windows SEH Exception would be more appropiate. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)
 
Let's take your example: In your case you'd failfast if DoWork() calls "throw new ArgumentException()", "throw new NullReferenceException()" or "throw new AccessViolationException".

What I'd be interested in is to determine, if for example a thrown AccessViolation is an ordinary .NET Exception or a Windows SEH Exception (?) that's caused by an actual access violation.

Comment: One more note: Your line " "corrupted state" is more a flag on any other type of exception than an exception on its own" is pretty much what I'm looking for: What is this flag, can it be read from .NET?

Comment: not what I initially intended to achieve - but I guess for now I'm gonna have to stick to "it can't be done because it shouldn't be done".
Thanks nevertheless.